# AD Query: Disabled Accounts still in Groups

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to have a query that finds all users in Active Directory that are disabled, but are also members of **ALL** groups - or All groups except for 1?

Tried the following:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(objectCategory=group)(name=*))
```

Comment: You mean all the groups you have in AD? As if you've for instance 147 groups, you want to know which disabled users belong to those 147 (or 146) groups?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - for example, I want all users that have been disabled that are in groups other than our generic "Domain Users" group

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with Powershell:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {enabled -eq $false} -properties memberof | where { ($_.memberof | measure).count -gt 1} | select samaccountname,name
```

The first part, you get all the users that are disabled, and you get the `memberof` property (not included by default). The second part, you `measure` the `memberof` property, then get the `count` and check if it's `gt` (Greater Than) 1.